# Is there a Lexicographic PriorityQueue in Python's standard library?

Tags: python-3.x, priority-queue, lexicographic-ordering

I have a set of pairs of numbers (i.e. 2-tuples) which I want to use as the priorities for a priority queue.

I found [`queue.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) in the Python documentation, but examples I have seen of this class suggest that it is meant to take numbers rather than tuples. I also called `help(PriorityQueue)` and read that "Entries are typically tuples of the form: (priority number, data)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PriorityQueue` data structure, and the `heapq` library it is based on, only use priorities for comparisons (i.e. `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`). The priorities can be any data type which supports those comparison operations.

In fact, this is exactly why a tuple of the form `(priority, data)` can be put into a priority queue at all - the queue doesn't treat the different parts of the tuple differently, or directly look inside the tuple to extract its parts, or even check that it is a tuple. It just compares them, and that means first comparing their priorities (since the priority is the first element of the tuple).

This works the other way around, too - if each data item `x` is its own priority, then you can put `x` into the queue directly without having to wrap it in a tuple like `(x, x)`.

Comment: +1 Ah, so I can define a `Priority` class that uses operator overloading (e.g. `__leq__`, etc) to have the lexicographical ordering that I want.

Comment: @Galen You can, or you can use tuples, since they are ordered lexicographically. If your requirements are more complex than just lexicographic ordering then it can make sense to write a class and implement an ordering for it, though.

Comment: That's even better. I guess I assumed they either didn't have an order built-in or used some other order (e.g. [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_order)). But lexicographical ordering certainly makes sense as a default behaviour.